# Are $3$, $9$ the only natural numbers $n$ for which both $2^n-n$ and $2^n+n$ are prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

I searched for natural numbers $n$, where $2^n-n$ and $2^n+n$ are both prime for the range of $n \le 10^5$ on PARI/GP and found that 3, 9 are the only solutions in this range.

Note that since  $2^n-n$, $2^n$, $2^n+n$ are in arithmetic progression and $2^n$ is not divisible by 3, $n$ must be a multiple of 3.

Questions:

> $(1)$ Are $3$, $9$ the only natural numbers $n$ for which both $2^n-n$ and $2^n+n$ are prime?
>
> $(2)$ If not, then can you prove or disprove that there are finite natural numbers of this type?

Comment: guess mod 5 was too complicated.

Comment: Ignoring small factors, the chance that either is prime is about$1/\ln (2^n)=1/(n\ln 2)$.  The chance that both are prime is the square of that, or $2.08/n^2$.  This has a finite sum, so I expect a finite number of solutions.

Comment: Since you have checked up to $10^5$, and the tail of my sum is $\sum_{n=10^5}^\infty 2.08/n^2\approx 2/10^5$, I would put the chances of any more solutions as $0.00002$

Comment: but 31% of valid n values  restricted to by 2, and 3 have small factors ( <13).

Comment: @Empy2 how do you know that the chance for finding either prime is $1/ \ln (2^n)$ ?

Comment: The Prime Number Theorem says there  are about $x/\ln x$ primes less than $x$, so the chance of a random $y$ being prime is about $1/\ln y$

Comment: turn out I forgot to account for mod 2 losses, so over 62% have small factors.

Comment: There are $30\ 879$ candidates (both $2^n-n$ and $2^n+n$ have no prime factor below $10^5$) in the range $[10^5,10^7]$

Comment: Upto $n=250\ 000$ , there is no other pair.